# How to define imshow( ) in ipython

Tags: ipython, imshow

I was given the code itself from the prof. so theoretically it should work, but I am getting an error.

```
import pyfits as pf
target_i = pf.getdata('file.fits')
header = pf.getheader('file.fits')
imshow(target_i,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')
```

When I put in the imshow command it says 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'.  Im assuming this means I need to define imshow?  How would I do this?  I can ask the professor if need be, but I am quite the procrastinator on this project and I don't think he would appreciate learning that I just started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ipython, the easiest way to import imshow is just to add this line to the top of your code:

```
%pylab
```

or

```
%pylab inline
```

This will import imshow from matplotlib directly into your namespace.  It's surprising that it thinks imshow is a module... did you import it or define it as a variable somewhere prior?

Comment: So, I just tried the %pylab inline and it gave me a usage error?  SO I used %pylab, and it gave me this huge list of stuff which Im assuming is good (or expected)but now when I get to the imshow its now saying it is not defined.

As for the importing/defining question, nope, the code above is all I really did with the exception of messing around with it a little (like putting pf.imshow instead).  But I am so inept with programming I may have made it worse lol

Comment: Try `plt.imshow(...)`

Does that work?

Here's where I'm getting it: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

Comment: You can also tell your prof to consider not to using `%pylab` or `--pylab` it is deprecated, and the IPython developper ask people not to use it exactly for these problem. Happy slacking.